# JmDNS does not work properly

Tags: java, networking, zeroconf, mdns, jmdns

At the moment i am working with the version 3.4.1 from the sourceforge page. I tried all the simple examples for registering and resolving the services. My problem is that my ServiceListener is just calling the serviceAdded method. It cannot resolve my webservices.

I experienced that the newest 3.5.1 version from github works far better resolving my webservices, but the processes as well on the server side as on the client side stop after a very short period of time. In my case this is unacceptable, because i have to listen for new services as long as i explicitly close the multicast sockets.

Unfortunately i have no idea what they changed since version 3.4.1.

I hope anyone could help me fixing my problems at version 3.4.1 or explaining me what to do in version 3.5.1 that both sides do not close their sockets.

Comment: This seems way too broad for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: At the moment it would be enough if there is anyone out there who had the same problem resolving services over 2 different devices in version 3.4.1 and could give a tip ;-)